# cannot click button : Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //*[')]'

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, automated-tests, bdd

i tested my xpath on devtools and it works but on my code when i compile my programme i have this message error :  Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')].

The second error is : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]"}

this my html :

[image]

all view (my button is on div id='mage'):

[image]

and the my page object :

```
public class MageReferentiel {


WebDriver webdriver;

public MageReferentiel(WebDriver rwebDriver) {
    webdriver = rwebDriver;
    PageFactory.initElements(webdriver, this);
}

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]" )
@CacheLookup
WebElement btnConnexion;

public void clickConnexion() {  
        WebElement webelement = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btnConnexion));
        btnConnexion.click();
}
```

}

the stpe definition :

```
 @When("l utilisateur choisi le referentiel")
public void l_utilisateur_choisi_le_referentiel() throws Exception {
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        mr.clickConnexion();
    }
```

in fact I have two panels for each i have the same text name and properties , each represents an application but to access the second panel you have to click on the second connection button to go to the home page and after that I will start the tests on the forms

i I found the button with the xpath : //*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')] without intercting with the application ,i can see it the element is available it's the button that i want to click but even with adding the webDriverWait or implicit wait i can't click on it

Thanks

Comment: Is that in iframe ?

Comment: @Prophet what you proposed to me as an answer doesn't work that's why I'm wondering once again

Comment: @cruisepandey the second photo has an iframe but my button is in the last div, (i dont know if do I have to handle with the iframe because my button is on the last div with "id=mage". How To Check if a Page Is in an iFrame ?

Comment: @Prophet i swear I tested all of them

Comment: @Prophet can you tell me please how to check if a page Is in an iFrame ?

Comment: @Prophet it's okay , thanks for your feed back in the first question

Comment: You have to check the HTML of that page. Go from the element you want to access and up to the body. If you see element with tag name `iframe` this is an iframe. If no - no. Normally iframe includes a big block of elements so it will appear far from your element, closer to the page top.

Comment: Have you verified this way for single element //button[text()='Connexion'] if got more than 1 
((//button[text()='Connexion'])[1]) based on the index will it work for you?

Comment: @YaDavMaNish i tested it for the two button it worked just un devtools but not on my code i have the same error

Comment: @jerando ok, then try with the JavascriptExecutor that might help with this